Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS update: What to do with ppa-purge?
I want to upgrade from Ubuntu 22.04 LTS to 24.04 LTS.
However, by doing sudo do-release-upgrade or sudo do-release-upgrade --allow-third-party, I always get the following error:
Could not calculate the upgrade 

An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade. 

This was likely caused by: 
* Unofficial software packages not provided by Ubuntu 
Please use the tool 'ppa-purge' from the ppa-purge 
package to remove software from a Launchpad PPA and 
try the upgrade again. 

What should I do with ppa-purge?
I just want to upgrade and find it extremely annoying that it does not work out of the box.
ll /etc/apt/sources.list.d gives
deadsnakes-ubuntu-ppa-jammy.list
deadsnakes-ubuntu-ppa-jammy.list.distUpgrade
deadsnakes-ubuntu-ppa-jammy.list.save
docker.list
docker.list.distUpgrade
docker.list.save
google-chrome.list
google-chrome.list.distUpgrade
google-chrome.list.save
linux_clients_seafile_com_seadrive_deb_jammy.list
linux_clients_seafile_com_seadrive_deb_jammy.list.distUpgrade
linux_clients_seafile_com_seadrive_deb_jammy.list.save
linux_clients_seafile_com_seafile_deb_jammy.list
linux_clients_seafile_com_seafile_deb_jammy.list.distUpgrade
linux_clients_seafile_com_seafile_deb_jammy.list.save
mattermost_stable.list
mattermost_stable.list.distUpgrade
mattermost_stable.list.save
mono-official-stable.list
mono-official-stable.list.distUpgrade
mono-official-stable.list.save
obsproject-ubuntu-obs-studio-jammy.list
obsproject-ubuntu-obs-studio-jammy.list.distUpgrade
obsproject-ubuntu-obs-studio-jammy.list.save
teams.list
teams.list.distUpgrade
teams.list.save
teleport.list
teleport.list.distUpgrade
teleport.list.save
zotero.list
zotero.list.distUpgrade
zotero.list.save

How to purge all of them? It always says "Could not find package list for PPA":
X:~$ sudo ppa-purge ppa:deadsnakes-ubuntu-ppa-jammy
Updating packages lists
PPA to be removed: ppa:deadsnakes-ubuntu-ppa-jammy ppa:deadsnakes-ubuntu-ppa-jammy
Warning:  Could not find package list for PPA: ppa:deadsnakes-ubuntu-ppa-jammy ppa:deadsnakes-ubuntu-ppa-jammy
X:~$ sudo ppa-purge ppa:deadsnakes
Updating packages lists
PPA to be removed: ppa:deadsnakes ppa:deadsnakes
Warning:  Could not find package list for PPA: ppa:deadsnakes ppa:deadsnakes
X:~$ sudo ppa-purge ppa:deadsnakes/ubuntu
Updating packages lists
PPA to be removed: deadsnakes ubuntu
Warning:  Could not find package list for PPA: deadsnakes ubuntu
X:~$ sudo ppa-purge ppa:deadsnakes/ubuntu/ppa
Updating packages lists
PPA to be removed: deadsnakes/ubuntu ppa
Warning:  Could not find package list for PPA: deadsnakes/ubuntu ppa

A star does not help, unfortunately:
$ sudo ppa-purge ppa:*
[sudo] password for X: 
Updating packages lists
PPA to be removed: ppa:* ppa:*
Warning:  Could not find package list for PPA: ppa:* ppa:*


Disable PPAs within software-properties-gtk, more importantly run sudo apt update and sudo apt upgrade before trying to install 24.04.  In order to run ppa-purge you need to know which PPA packages you have installed. [Edit] your question to include the necessary information to answer your question. If you don't care about what you remove you should be able to run sudo ppa-purge ppa:* and just wildcard remove all ppa packages.

Thanks. Unfortunately, the wildcard does not work. I edited my question accordingly.

Did you try to disable all PPAs like told above and run sudo apt update? There may be some newer packages left around from the PPAs, but on the other hand 24.04 may have packages even newer than those. It is possible to downgrade packages that are too new later, if they don't prevent the release upgrade process. Do you still have packages you need to donwgrade?

In my case, although I got the same warning as you, I didn't need to use ppa-purge command at all. (Different packages from you though. I'm coming from Ubuntu Studio 23.10 using a bunch of special audio packages)
Further down in the warning it mentioned viewing more details in /var/log/dist-upgrade/{date}/ and specifically apt.log and main.log
I ran tail -n 300 main.log and was able to see some errors where it was unable to find replacement packages for the upgrade, for example:

2024-08-26 13:20:37,221 DEBUG Searching for replacement for linux-headers-6.5.0-35-lowlatency
2024-08-26 13:20:37,221 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for linux-headers-6.5.0-35-lowlatency
2024-08-26 13:20:37,221 DEBUG Searching for replacement for linux-headers-6.5.0-41-lowlatency
2024-08-26 13:20:37,221 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for linux-headers-6.5.0-41-lowlatency
2024-08-26 13:20:37,222 DEBUG Searching for replacement for linux-headers-6.5.0-42-lowlatency
2024-08-26 13:20:37,222 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for linux-headers-6.5.0-42-lowlatency
2024-08-26 13:20:37,222 DEBUG Searching for replacement for linux-image-6.5.0-35-lowlatency
2024-08-26 13:20:37,222 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for linux-image-6.5.0-35-lowlatency
2024-08-26 13:20:37,222 DEBUG Searching for replacement for linux-image-6.5.0-41-lowlatency
2024-08-26 13:20:37,222 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for linux-image-6.5.0-41-lowlatency
2024-08-26 13:20:37,222 DEBUG Searching for replacement for linux-image-6.5.0-42-lowlatency
2024-08-26 13:20:37,222 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for linux-image-6.5.0-42-lowlatency
2024-08-26 13:20:37,222 DEBUG Searching for replacement for linux-lowlatency-headers-6.5.0-35
2024-08-26 13:20:37,222 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for linux-lowlatency-headers-6.5.0-35
2024-08-26 13:20:37,263 DEBUG Searching for replacement for wine-staging
2024-08-26 13:20:37,263 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for wine-staging
2024-08-26 13:20:37,263 DEBUG Searching for replacement for wine-staging-amd64
2024-08-26 13:20:37,263 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for wine-staging-amd64
2024-08-26 13:20:37,263 DEBUG Searching for replacement for wine-staging-i386:i386
2024-08-26 13:20:37,263 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for wine-staging-i386:i386
2024-08-26 13:20:37,263 DEBUG Searching for replacement for winehq-staging
2024-08-26 13:20:37,263 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for winehq-staging

So I removed the main packages that appeared to be causing the issues:
sudo apt remove linux-headers-lowlatency
sudo apt remove wine-staging

*Note: your packages that need removing will obviously be different from mine, so don't just run those commands!
And then I retried the upgrade, and this time it worked (honestly I didn't even remove everything that I saw errors on in the main.log file, just the main packages. For example I saw some errors on perl, python, and ruby packages too, but didn't manually remove those. However, I did run a sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade && sudo apt autoremove && sudo apt autoclean to make sure everything was up-to-date and any extraneous dependencies were also removed before retrying the system upgrade).
Good luck - hope this helps!

Yeah, can confirm - took me an hour or two to hunt down all packages that caused errors, but once those were removed the process worked without touching PPAs.

tl;dr See the associated launchpad page for the ppa to find out its real name.
I don't think you hit upon the real name for this one in your iterations. For example, the command to add it is sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa as found on its launchpad page so to purge it, you should type
sudo ppa-purge ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
I added this ppa to a jammy virtual machine which confirmed that the sources list it adds is named deadsnakes-ubuntu-ppa-jammy.list That matches the one shown in the output in your question.
And, I confirmed that ppa-purge successfully purges it.
$ sudo ppa-purge ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
Updating packages lists
PPA to be removed: deadsnakes ppa
Package revert list generated:


Disabling deadsnakes PPA from 
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/deadsnakes-ubuntu-ppa-jammy.list
Updating packages lists
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
PPA purged successfully

I'll leave it as an exercise for you to hunt down the true names of the other ppas you need to purge; the main point here is that the name of the list they add is not necessarily the name of the ppa so you have to consult their launchpad pages (or the copious notes you took when you added all those ppas).
